# Java initialization bytecode skipped

Tags: java, bytecode

In the bytecode of a class file, as per `javap -c ...`, there is a block of code which is responsible for initializing a static field within the class. However, there are two if statements, `ifne` and `ifeq`, which are placed after each other:

```
27: ifne 120
30: ifeq 119
```

The initialization block is between the offsets 37 and 115, and is required in order to initialize the static variable contained within the class. My understanding is that `ifne` will branch if the value on the stack is not 0, and that `ifeq` will branch if the value on the stack is 0, which means that it will branch regardless.

My question is: if the initialization block is simply skipped by these branches, why is the variable initialized later on? I can't find any branches to the block, so how can it have been ran if the code branches off elsewhere?

Edit: more bytecode

```
0: getstatic      #602  // static integer field
3: istore         25
...
25: iload         25
27: ifne          120
30: ifeq          119
33: goto          37
36: athrow
37: new           #6    // class java/io/File
40: dup
41: getstatic     #615  // static string containing filename
...
56: invokespecial #9    // Method java/io/File."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
...
112: putstatic    #14   // static File referenced later on
```

Comment: Can you show the Java source and more of the bytecode?

Comment: Yep, not nearly enough info to go on.

Comment: @arshajii Added more bytecode

Comment: In addition to what @codenheim says, the above code looks suspiciously like there's a try/catch block somewhere nearby, and that can affect the branching of the code greatly.

Comment: @HotLicks I opened the code in the Bytecode Visualizer plugin for Eclipse, which showed a try/catch block surrounding offsets 5-33. What effect does this have on branching?

Comment: Control from that range can branch to the corresponding catch and finally regions.

Comment: To get a better idea of what it is branching on you need to show a few opcode *before* 25 as well, to find out what value is loaded onto the stack for the branch on offset 30.

Answer (score 6):

Java is not my strongest VM, but I generally understand the opcodes.

```
27: ifne 120
30: ifeq 119
```

A conditional branch pops the top value off the stack. So this is not an unconditional branch, it is 2 branch instructions based on 2 different (consecutive) stack values. In short, it consumes 2 different values.

So if you have 0 and 1 on the stack, it would fall through without branching.

Also, static field initialization is not guaranteed to execute immediately, the JVM spec that I have (old one) says it will execute lazily, on the first non-constant access to the class. That may not be relevant to your question, but is worth mentioning.

Last but not least, not all bytecode is valid. Obfuscators will insert invalid / dead code that is either unreachable, redundant, or "obfuscated" by definition.

Comment: Yep: "The value must be of type int. It is popped from the operand stack and compared against zero."

Comment: You are right, the execution of the initializer will be lazy. That’s why using a class initializer, e.g. `static final Type LAZY_CONSTANT = compute();`, is the recommended “thread safe lazy initialization” pattern.